# Oracle: is it possible to compare values in Long column with values in Clob column

Tags: oracle11g, compare, long-integer, clob

There is a table X having a "Long" Column and Table Y having a "CLOB" Column. Data has been migrated from Table X to Table Y. Now I need to verify if the data got converted correctly. I had the idea of using casting, but seems "Long" values cannot be converted to "Varchar" in select statements. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Eg:

SELECT LONG_COLUMN FROM TABLE_X
Minus
SELECT CLOB_COLUMN FROM TABLE_Y

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: `long` can't easily be converted/compared to other datatypes and `clob` can't be used in a `minus` operation!

Fortunately, both of these can be overcome by using PL/SQL. Longs and clobs can be implicitly converted into `varchar2` when they are selected in PL/SQL blocks. You can load these into a nested-table, then use the `multiset except` operator to find the differences between them:

```
create table long_t ( x long );
create table lob_t  ( x clob );

insert into long_t values ('1');
insert into long_t values ('2');
insert into lob_t values ('1');

declare
  type t is table of varchar2(32767);
  longs t;
  clobs t;

  diff t;
begin
  select x bulk collect into longs from long_t;
  select x bulk collect into clobs from lob_t;
  diff := longs multiset except clobs;

  for i in 1 .. diff.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(diff(i));  
  end loop;

  diff := clobs multiset except longs;

  for i in 1 .. diff.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(diff(i));  
  end loop;
end;
/

anonymous block completed
2
```

If your tables contain more than a couple of thousand rows, you're likely to run out of memory using the above as-is, as the whole table will be loaded at once. If you've got an `id` or similar column on each table, then it would be best to fetch and compare rows in ranges, e.g. 1-1000, 1001-2000 and so on.